# Segmentaton Fault With Assembly Program

Tags: assembly, x86-64

I made this simple assembly program:

```
.text
    .globl _start

    _start:

        jmp MyCallStatement

        Shellcode:

            popq %rsi
            xorq %rax, %rax
            movb %al, 0x9(%rsi)
            movq %rsi, 0xa(%rsi)
            movq %rax, 0xe(%rsi)
            movb $11, %al
            movq %rsi, %rbx
            leaq 0xa(%rsi), %rcx
            leaq 0xe(%rsi), %rdx
            int $0x80

        MyCallStatement:

            call Shellcode
            ShellVariable:
                .ascii "/bin/bashABBBBCCCC"
```

The program compiles fine and links well. However, when I run it, I get a segmentation fault. Why is that?

Comment: After you `call Shellcode` you return to executing the `/bin/bashABBBBCCCC` string as code which is very likely to segfault.

Comment: The way you are running this (not on the stack) will cause a problem. Your code is in a `text` section which is read only (and execute). You can't write. I'd expect lines like `movb %al, 0x9(%rsi)` would fail.

Comment: Also, stack is usually out of 32 bit range, you should use 64 bit `syscall` (when you will use it as payload, that is)

Comment: I still don't understand why will I get a segmentation fault

Comment: Is this for Linux? You know that you need to do amd64 system calls through the `syscall` instruction as opposed to `int $0x80`?

Comment: @FUZxxl yes this is for linux, but I don't see a difference between syscall and int $0x80

Comment: @DarkEagle `int $0x80` is for 32 bit system calls, `syscall` is for 64 bit system calls. Both the call numbers, the calling convention and the argument sizes are different.